# Showing $\lim_{x\to \infty } e^x-e^{x-\frac{1}{x}} = \infty$

Tags: limits

I need to show that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty } e^x-e^{x-\frac{1}{x}} =  \infty$$

I tried to simplify the term and got

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1) = \lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{e^{x}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)}{e^\frac{1}{x}}$$

but from here I can't show that the limit is infinity because the term inside the parentheses goes to $0$ when $x$ approach infinity, I tried l'Hopital but it didn't work, any ideas how to continue?

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$e^x-e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{e^x}x \cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{-\frac1x} \to \infty\cdot 1=\infty $$

using that as $t\to 0$ we have $\frac{e^t-1}t\to 1$ and eventually $e^x\ge x^2$.

---

More in general, by the same approach, for any $a>0$

$$e^x-e^{x-\frac{1}{x^a}} =\frac{e^x}{x^a} \cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^a}}-1}{-\frac1{x^a}} \to \infty\cdot 1=\infty$$

and for $a\le 0$ by $b=-a\ge 0$

$$e^x-e^{x-\frac{1}{x^a}}=e^x-e^{x-x^b} =e^x\left(1-\frac1{e^{x^b}}\right)\to \infty$$

---

As an alternative approach, using that $e^t \ge 1+t$

$$e^x-e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}=e^x-\frac{e^{x}}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\ge e^x-\frac{e^x}{1+\frac1x}=\frac{e^x}{1+x}\to \infty$$